# Enviar arquivos locais para o Google Cloud Storage em Scala

Tags: java, google, google-app-engine, scala

Como faço para enviar um arquivo local para o Google Cloud Storage usando a linguagem Scala? Esse arquivo precisa ser acessível publicamente para download.

[Post em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540158/how-to-easily-send-local-file-to-google-cloud-storage-in-scala/25540378#25540378)

Comment: É legal você declarar que está [fazendo cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540158/how-to-easily-send-local-file-to-google-cloud-storage-in-scala). E já vi que muitas das suas perguntas são assim. Não sei se lá no SOen precisa fazer, já que é mais difícil alguém falar português lá do que inglês aqui. Confira a meta-discussão: [Onde faço pergunta, SO em Português ou em Inglês?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/735/201)

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.